# How to chain external commands in VIM?

Tags: bash, vim, xclip

If I select the following text in a VIM buffer in VISUAL mode

```
f() { 
  echo "f"; 
} 
f
```

and then execute

```
:'<,'>w !xclip | !eval "$(xclip -o)"
```

I get

```
/bin/bash: eval: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: eval: line 3: `feval f() {'
```

How can I chain the 2 commands properly so that the first one copies the VISUAL selection to the system clipboard and the second one evaluates it by using `eval` ?

Comment: Try `:'<,'>w !xclip | eval "$(xclip -o)"` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
'<,'>w !xclip | eval "$(xclip -o)"
```

The `!` needs to be used once and vim would run the command as one command.

Answer (score 4):

```
:'<,'>!xclip && eval "$(xclip -o)"
```

runs perfectly fine in my test (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with bash 4.3, vim 7.4), and transforms the 4 lines to a single character 'f'. Replacing `&&` with `|` also works although it is not recommended.

I don't think running shell commands with vim is very different from running in the usual shell, and it shouldn't be.

Comment: Hm. It really works, but I thought that I should place ! before any external command...

Comment: @ka3ak you have to put it beofre each external *statement*, which may well include several commands.